# How to switch the focused window with Xlib

Tags: c, xlib

I'm making a small keyboard-oriented X window manager and I was wondering how I would switch focus to another window on the screen. I am aware of XSetInputFocus() but how would I get the window to switch to? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use XQueryTree on the root window to find all the top-level windows.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yeah, that's what I ended up doing, Thanks!